# Creating class instances in a list

Tags: c#, list, class, logging, foreach

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

The class Logger should declare a collection of `LogMedia` as a member variable, and only needs to declare a single function: `void LogException( Exception ex )`. Inside this function, you should loop through all `LogMedia` instances, and call a virtual function defined in each one.

**What I'm having trouble understanding is how can I implement a loop that goes through all these instances. Or maybe rather, how do I create these instances?**

**Logger Class**

```
public class Logger
    {
       static List<LogMedia> m_loggers = new List<LogMedia>();

         **//Should I create som instances here?**
        public static void LogException(Exception ex)
        {
            foreach(var i in m_loggers)
            {
                i.LogMessage(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        }
    }
```

**LogMediaClass***:Then I was to create the class logmedia and three other classes where"Each of the derived classes should then override this function in the LogMedia class. How can I create instances of these three classes such that I can loop through them as shown in Logger?*

```
public class LogMedia
    {
        public virtual void LogMessage(string Message) { } //virtual function that doesen't do anything

    }
    public class OutputWindowLogMedia : LogMedia
    {
        public override void LogMessage(string Message)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Message);
        }
    }
    class TextFileLogMedia : LogMedia
    {
        public override void LogMessage(string Message)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Temp\\xxx\\xxxx.txt");
            writer.WriteLine(Message + " the error occured at: ");
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
    class EmailLogMedia : LogMedia
    {
        public override void LogMessage(string Message)
        {


            const string senderID = "xxx@gmail.com"; // use sender's email id here..
            const string toAddress = "xxx@some.com";
            const string senderPassword = "xxxx"; // sender password here...
            try
            {
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com", // smtp server address here...
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword),
                    Timeout = 30000,
                };
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(senderID, toAddress, "erroe", "error");
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Error sending mail:" + ex.Message);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Two tangentally related notes: 1) Why not use an abstract class/method instead of a virtual method with no base implementation? 2) You should wrap that `StreamWriter` up in a `using` statement to make sure it's properly disposed.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to programmatically find and instantiate all classes that derive from LogMedia?

Comment: Yes. I want fo be able to loop through all instances of class that override/inherit the Logmedia classs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please initialize in a **static constructor**.

Add all the loggers in there. It will be ensured that whenever `LogException()` is called the list is populated, seeing that the function is static.

Also just a side thought, do make the base LogMedia as `abstract` or favorably an `interface`.

Now there is a side -affect to this as well, whenever a new LogMedia is added sometime in the future, an `Add` call must be added in the static constructor.

This might induce bugs in big projects in maintainence, so to avoid that, add an `InitializeAllLoggers()` method in the static constructor and put the following code in it.

```
foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList())
{
    foreach (Type classType in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
         if (classType.IsClass
                    && !classType.IsAbstract
                    && classType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(LogMedia)))                     
         {
              m_loggers.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(classType) as LogMedia);
         }
    }
}
```

This will ensure that whenever a new type of `LogMedia` is created, its automatically added to the loggers list.

Comment: Initalizing in a static constructor? Could yoe explain a bit more what you mean. I should create the list from LogMeda like I did right? And then Add all instances to the list? no?

Comment: Add a static constructor to your `Logger` class like so: `static Logger() {m_loggers.Add(new OutputWindowLogMedia());      m_loggers.Add(new TextFileLogMedia());m_loggers.Add(new EmailLogMedia());}`

Answer (score 1):

straight forward method:

```
public Logger()
{
    loggers.Add(new OutputWindowLogMedia ());
    loggers.Add(new TextFileLogMedia ());
    loggers.Add(new EmailLogMedia ());
}
```

If you want something more extensible look at MEF or just use log4net, which is configuration driven.

Comment: Shoudn't I be able to do the following: m_loggers.Add(new emailLogMedia()); But I get the Error that m_logger is a field but is used like a type

Comment: My spidey senses tell me that you are adding that line inside of the class definition instead of inside the constructor

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is:

1. Add Register and Unregister static methods to Logger class. The methods just adds / removes the member to m_loggers list.
2. Your code uses the methods to register / unregister loggers.